# Optimal declaration of variables with regards to scope

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, scope

I ask this question mostly in regards to C programming, but insights on any language are welcome.

When it comes to C, I know it only lets variable declarations occur at the very beginning of a block of code. And I have been under the impression that one should declare all variables to be used within a function at the very beginning of the function. But there are many occasions where I'll have a variable that is only used within a loop (or similar block).

an example would be a temporary variable for some return value:

```
while ( whatever ) {
  int ret;
  ret = getSomeValue();
}
```

or where some state may need to be held:

```
while ( whatever ) {
  static int count=0;
  count++;
}
```

I was wondering if it is considered improper, or, if there is any negative impact to declaring variables within control flow blocks such as if-else, for loops, while loops, etc.

Should variables always be declared with the tightest possible scope? what about for static declaration?

**Edit**:
Okay, I probably should have said I'm aware C99 is more liberal when it comes to where you declare variables, but from a lot of C code I see, they're still usually declared at top. Also, I use VS2K8 which still complains about declarations.

Also, seeing as I've had 2 votes to close this thead, I'll make it clear that I'm more concerned with the performance and compiler aspects than I am with anything stylistic.

Comment: Pre-C99 they need to be at the beginning of a block...over 11 years ago. I think that's long enough to say "in C, you don't need to declare it in at the beginning." Also, as usual the answer is whichever is simplest and easier to read.

Comment: I know that in gcc, one of the older versions, it complained a lot when you tried to declare inside of loops, you would have to declare it outside of the loop.

Comment: Basically the same as [Where do you declare variables? The top of a method or when you need them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318943/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them).

Comment: "When it comes to C, I know it only lets variable declarations occur at the very beginning of a block of code" - in my best Leonard H McCoy voice: my god, man, where have you been?

Answer (score 7):

A rule of thumb is that variables should always be made as local as possible. Bonus points if you can make it `const`.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, the thing about declarations at the top of blocks is C89 and K&R, but since C99 you can mix declarations and statements. The style persists, probably for good reasons, but it's not required.

There was a time when some compilers would do a better job if you declared lots of local variables right where they were used, because it made register allocation better. Pre-C99, you had to declare them at the top of blocks or use a vendor-extension, but you could still decide to actually *use* each variable only in a local area of code.

It probably seemed important at one point to directly support this with more flexible declaration placement, but I suspect that these days the optimizers don't need that kind of help.

Some coding standards require declarations at the top of functions. I don't know if this is so you can find them or if it's just left over from the days where not doing that might limit backwards portability.

In general, the more formal the standard, the less it likes interleaving statements and declarations, except for loop control variables. Personally, I don't see the problem with it.

**Advantages of mixed declarations**: locality. Good for the compiler, good for the reader. What possible benefit can accrue from declaring a loop variable at the top of a function? Reusing a variable down the page for an unrelated purpose seems confusing and unwise in terms of possible unwanted interactions.

**Advantages of grouped declarations**: the code looks cleaner in a subjective way, you know where to go to find every declaration, and if the top of your function is too far away from the use of the variable, perhaps that's telling you that you need to extract a second or third function from the obviously too-big one.

Comment: Scoping and mixing are different kinds of things. OP deals with the former and you do with the latter. Can you please give some details about in-scope declarations?

Comment: Although they may exist, I'm not aware of a lot of facts or objective elements I can draw on to answer you. I can say that I believe in reducing side effects. And as with the Roger Zelazny Amber novels, I try to find a faint shadow of functional programming when writing C, so declaring variables right where they are used is my style.

Answer (score 2):

Where you declare a variable doesn't affect the code generation. All a functions variables a put on the stack before the first line of code even gets executed (at least this is observed behavior). As you already know, the rules about variable declaration a long dead. Declaring variables at the top has these advantages

- easier to read, when all variables can be found in the same place
- you don't need to worry about rearranging code if you need to suddenly access a variable before it is declared (unless of course, you purposely want to prevent this).

And yes, I would make variables as local as possible. If a variable is used only within a loop or control flow or even a meaningless {} pair (Which I have used to prevent name clashing), then declare them there. Take the famous n or i variable in for loops. If you have multiple, you will need a unique var name for each for loop, which would become annoying.