# C++ mixing of variable declarations and executables advtantage

Tags: c++

I have a conceptual question to help me as a fairly novice C++ programmer. What is the advantage, if any, of C++ allowing mixing, or "co-mingling", of declarations and executables? As I beginner, all I can think of is that this is not a feature available in C. And obviously, you can combine some lines of code by not having to declare variables at the beginning of a particular scope, but rather you could declare in the instruction itself. Wish I had more to tell you all but I really do not know. Maybe a push in the right direction would help! Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand. By "executables" do you in fact mean non-declarative statements? Are you asking why C++ allows us to declare variables at points other than the top of a function?

Comment: FWIW, C99 removed that restriction from C. That was 16 years ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4075246/560648

Answer (score 0):

This is REQUIRED in cases where you need to take a reference from the result of a function.

```
 SomeType& func();
....

... 
    ... Some code that is needed to make `func` work, for example 
    ... opening a file or initializing some global variables.
    SomeType& x = func();
...
```

It does not work to declare `x` at the start of a block, as C pre-C99 requires in this case, since references can not be declared without initializing the referant into the reference.

The other point is that you can avoid "default constructing" and then initializing a variable, which is a similar:

```
SomeType x(func());
```

would avoid calling the default constructor of `SomeType`.

But generally, the compiler will take care of removing unnecessary constructors, so it's much less of an issue than the first case.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage is making the code easier to read - instead of having a statement like `myVar = doSomething(p1, p2, p3);` and having to scroll all the way up to the beginning of the scope to recall what `myVar` was, you could have a single, clearer, one liner `MyClass myVar = doSomething(p1, p2, p3);`.

Comment: And then you can ruin it completely by writing `auto myVar = doSomething(p1, p2, p3)` because you're too lazy to make use of the type system :(

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three of advantages/benifits here.

*no uninitialized/default initialized values and better scoping*

```
int a = -1;
int b;
...   // Use of `a` is meaningless here, use of `b` is also dangerous
a = f(); b = g();
```

vs.

```
...  // Uses of `a` and `b` are compiler errors
int a = f(), b = g();
```

*more effective object creation*

```
Object o;                // default ctor
...
o = Object(1, 2, 'a');   // ctor + move-assignement operator
```

vs.

```
...
Object o(1, 2, 'a');     // ctor
```

*RAII*

```
mtx.lock();
...
mtx.unlock();
```

vs.

```
{
    std::lock_guard<mutex> guard(mtx);  // implicit mtx.lock()
    ...
}  // automatically generated mtx.unlock();
```